# veracode error CWE-454: external initialization

Tags: c, veracode

I receive this error from the following c code.

```
if (system("clear") == -1)
{
   fprintf(stderr, "system() failed");
}
```

Comment: Don't use `system()` but figure out how to clear the terminal in c.  For example, if caller can manipulate the path it will not be the clear being called that you think it is.

Comment: I do not know why; but as @AllanWind suggested I would use something like ```printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J");``` to clear the screen (in POSIX systems).

Comment: I was curious... "\e[1;1H" aka "\e[;1H" means move cursor to top-left corner.  "\e[2J' means erase the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `system()`.  If caller of your program can manipulate the search path for command then any command named clear can be executed instead of the one you intended.  Implement the feature in C instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void clear() {
   // Move cursor to top-left corner and clear the erase entire screen
   fputs("\e[;1H\e[2J", stdout);
}
```